# How to pre populate PayPal's Digital Goods Flow's email address field

Tags: javascript, paypal, express-checkout

I am Integrating [Digital Goods Flow](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntegratingExpressCheckoutDG/) into my app but am having a hard time figuring out how to pre-populate/pre-fill the email address field.

I am setting the `expType` variable to `"instant"` so that The Digital Goods flow opens the Log in to your PayPal account page in a mini-browser, with a mask over my underlying page. How Do I pre-populate this mini-browser's email address field with a certain value?

I am also using Express Checkout and [these docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) show that you can set an EMAIL field to pre-populate the sign-in. I tried this method and it does not work on Digital Good's mini-browser login.

Comment: Generally you don't -- PayPal uses their cookie to determine if, and how, to prefill the email field.

Comment: @geewiz but do you know of a way to go around this using Digital Good's flow?